# How would you set up conditions for a while statement?

Tags: java

```
    }while (x.equals("a")!= true);
```

For this condition that's apart of a do-while loop, how would you make the condition for both "a" and "b".

Comment: `x.equals("a")!= true` can be reduced to `!x.equals("a")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the do block to execute when x is neither "a" or "b", then try this:

```
do {
    // your code here
} while(!x.equals("a") && !x.equals("b"));
```

Answer (score 0):

while (!x.equals("a") && !x.equals("b"));

Im assuming youre programming in java